# Selecting words that are phonetically similar with different beginnings

Tags: mysql, soundex

I'm noticing a pattern with the returned results of the MySQL soundex function: if it starts the same and ends different, it's a match, if it starts different and ends the same, it isn't. Examples:

```
SELECT 
  SOUNDEX('off') AS off_soundex,
  SOUNDEX('oph') AS oph_soundex,
  SOUNDEX('oaf') AS oaf_soundex;
```

All return "O100", which would be a match. However:

```
SELECT 
  SOUNDEX('cite') AS cite_soundex,
  SOUNDEX('sight') AS sight_soundex;
```

returns S300 and C300 - not a match.

```
SELECT 
  SOUNDEX('sity') AS sity_soundex,
  SOUNDEX('city') AS city_soundex;
```

Also return S300 and C300. What this means is that someone can mistype "city" as "cite" and find city but not if they mistype it "sity". Quite why "sight" is a match for "sity" is just strange: since soundex("height") returns H230, I would have thought that "sight" would return "S230" - of course this would break the "sight" "cite" match and fixing it would break the "cite" "city" match. It's as if they're trying to shoehorn a one-to-one relationship into phonetics where one does not really exist.

What I'm wondering is, short of writing a lookup table of known words and likely mispellings, is there a better solution to this?

Comment: You might look into the Double Metaphone offerings. Earlier implementations are without charge, but October 12, 2009 version is not free software.  https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/doubleMetaphone.html

Comment: This problem is far beyond what MySQL can do.  Change the tags to get more people to weigh in on the phonetic question you are really asking.  (Sorry, I don't have suggestions.)  After getting an acceptable algorithm, then you can look at whether a database is the right place to implement the search.